# Show in org-agenda the org-entries with deadlines only after a specific time

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, deadline

How do I show the todo entries that have deadlines only after a specific time? This helps agenda display more accurately what are needed to be displayed.

For example, I'm hoping for some thing like

```
* TODO Do this.
  DEADLINE: <2025-01-01> AFTER: <2024-10-31>
```

As you see, I have a todo whose due is very distant from now. However, I want to start worrying about it only after `<2024-10-31>`. Is it possible to let it show in the `org-agenda` after that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it globally with the variable `org-deadline-warning-days`. For example, to start showing all tasks 3 days before the deadline:

```
(setq org-deadline-warning-days 3)
```

If you want to set it individually, you can use the following construct in the timestamp itself:

```
DEADLINE: <2021-07-20 dom -3d>
```

Here, you can also use other modifiers, such as weeks, months and years: `-3w`, `-3m`, `-3y`.

Comment: `DEADLINE: <2021-07-20 dom -3d>` does not work for me.. the corresponding org entry is shown only on `2021-07-20` as an entry with deadline in the agenda (default agenda view for current week), but not in other days.

Comment: Weird.. it's indeed included in the [official manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html#Repeated-tasks).. is this a deprecated old feature that is not taken off from the manual?

Comment: I am on org 9.4.6-g5a03ad / Emacs 27.1 and it works fine here. What version are you on?

Comment: I just tested a bit more here, and noticed that the warning only appears for **today** (given today's date is included in the warning period). If you browse to other days in the future between today and the deadline, the warning doesn't appear (i.e. it doesn't show for all days in the warning interval, just _today_).

Comment: That's indeed the case! Thank you so much for your help!